# WSDL1.1: request-response is an abstract notion

Tags: wsdl

I was going through the WSDL specification 1.1 where I encountered the following lines:

"Note that a request-response operation is an abstract notion; a particular binding must be consulted to determine how the messages are actually sent: within a single communication (such as a HTTP request/response), or as two independent communications (such as two HTTP requests)"

Can someone please provide me with an example for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: And you didn't searched by your own for [WSDL1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/ws-addr-wsdl/) and [abstract notion](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E41633_01/pt853pbh1/eng/pt/tibr/concept_UnderstandingProvidingWSDLDocuments-076201.html)?

Comment: @ckruczek: Thanks for the response with the links